# AngularJs controller issue while using it on two different Razor views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently working on a project using asp.net mvc with angular. 
The problem I'm having is that I need to use one angular controller on two different razor views, one being rendered as the "main" view and the second one as the partial within the first. 
Let's say that I have boolean flag set initially to false in angular, then within the partial view I've changed it to true. The issue I'm having is that logic used on the "main" view does not recognize any changes made from the partial, so if I'll try to access this flag from the "main" one it still will be set to false. 
Do you guys have any idea how to solve it? I'm new to angular, the only thing coming to my mind right now is to merge the views (but I really don't want to mess with the models, so that'll be the final option).

I'll highly appreciate any insights.

Comment: Too difficult without looking at the code. Please share some code or prepare a fiddle so you can get better support.

Comment: why you use Angular with razor?? .. maybe you can just use only one index.cshtml but other view use only html injected by angular with routing